# Ways to build Abstractive summarisation and what are it's challenges

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, bert, transformer

What are state of art techniques to build Abstractive summarisation on some paragraphs or articles and what kind of hurdles or challenges are there to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Text summarization is an active research topic and the question is very broad. For a detailed answer one has to study the state of the art, there's a [rich literature](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=nlp+abstractive+summarization) on the topic.

From a recent [survey paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0957417418307735):

> - Deep Learning Models capture both the syntactic and semantic structure.
> - Requirement of large data set limits the use of Deep Learning Models.